# Get values of complex JsonResult.Data

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

My function returns JsonResult:

```
var obj = new { pc = peopleCount, fp = finalPrice, os = osoba, dt = date, zd = zadatek };
return new JsonResult { Data = obj, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

and I'd like to get all values from JsonResult. It's simple if there is only one value, but here I have an object with 5 properies. How to get them? For now I have:

```
var getPrice = (JsonResult)GetBundleData(item.EventID);
var price = getPrice.Data;
```

and I can see that in `price` there are those values

[image]

but I can't get them by just using dot and property name. There are only `Equals()`, `GetHashCode()`, `GetType()` and `ToString()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access JsonResult data when testing in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232470/how-to-access-jsonresult-data-when-testing-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: there are lot of examples to do what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object

Answer (score 0):

since the compiler does not know the type of `price` at run time we can use `dynamic` for that purpose.

```
var getPrice = (JsonResult)GetBundleData(item.EventID);
dynamic price = getPrice.Data;
```

and use values like

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(price.dt);
```

> note that use dynamic if you are sure of properties of object else it
>   will throw exception in runtime

let suppose if i use `price.example` it will `build` just fine without any errors but when this function is called it will throw `exception` because it will not find `example` property in `price object`